# How is it posible to reset data with awk

Tags: awk

I have a big date  like this

```
"cetoo" "12364" "veli" "212" "ahmet" "12331283"
```

chage like this

```
ceto  1234
veli  212
ahmet 123123
```

Comment: I've given a naive answer below showing how to split the input into separate rows, but was careless in not realizing the output didn't match the question.  Can you explain what rules we need to follow to get the expected output?  Why does "cetoo" become "ceto", why does "12364" become "1234", etc. Do you see what I'm asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an working example, which is tested on RHEL platform:

```
$ cat a.out
"cetoo""12364""veli""212""ahmet""12331283"
"Chandu""0549""Rachael""123"

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""} {for (i=2;i<=NF; i +=4) print $i, $(i+2)}' a.out
cetoo 12364
veli 212
ahmet 12331283
Chandu 0549
Rachael 123
```

Comment: consider adding some explanation about what you did and why

Comment: thx dude it is useful for me.i m newbies :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "cetoo" "12364" "veli" "212" "ahmet" "12331283 " | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i, $(i+1); }'

cetoo 12364
veli 212
ahmet 12331283
```

Comment: Your output is different from the OP example. Virtual -1. If the question is soo bad, ask for clarification with a comment _before_ throwing an answer.

Comment: That's a really fair point, @gboffi, I definitely jumped the gun on that. Let's see what clarification I can get ...

Comment: OTOH, the OP could approve your answer as well... good luck, ciao

Comment: yes you are right my language is bad linux knowledge is to I try to do something thx for helping